# tabu m-column vertical alignment not working after package updates

Tags: tabu, vertical, alignment

After MIKTEX package updates vertical m-column alignment in tabu does not work anymore. See MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=3pt


Result using tabu:

\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X[p]| X[m]| X[b]|}
    \hline
    \centering header p &
    \centering header m &   
    \centering header b \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column 
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabu}

\vspace*{1cm}

Result using tabular:

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|m{0.3\linewidth}|b{0.3\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    \centering header p &
    \centering header m &   
    \centering header b \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column 
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

The results is:
[image: MWE mit tabu and tabular]

Both tables should be equal but m-column in tabu is broken.Does anyone know which package is responsible for that? Here is the list of packages that were updated:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just to mention it: TL2018 (fully updated) is also affected.

Comment: In my case I never use the `tabu` package alone, since it needs the `longtable`, `tabularx`, `array` and `multirrow` packages, if I compile your code with my normal configuration I have no problems, I get the same as with the tabular environment, you should know that tabu is not a self-contained package, it is a set of macros that other table libraries use to create beautiful tables ....

Comment: @JLeonV. do you have the 2018-04-01 latex release?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it's an honor to answer you... Yes, LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 3, And I compile with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6670 64-bit)

Comment: @JLeonV. it shouldn't work I think, can you check you have array.sty `2018/04/30 v2.4h`

Comment: In my miktex installation folder I have the `2018/04/07 v2.4g`, What I just noticed is that, in the case of my thesis work that uses a lot of packages, and all my tables are made with the tabu environment, I have no problems; but in the case of this example it works normal but in compilation messages the following appears before tabu is loaded: `LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 68, version
                `2008/09/09 'of package array,
                but only version
                `1998/05/13 v2.3m Tabular extension package (FMi) '
                is available`

Comment: @JLeonV. 1998!!!   you should clean up your tex input tree:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In order to ensure correct breakage of her/his thesis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## UPDATE 2019-01-14

A workaround for this issuse has been included in tabu 2.9 which has been submitted to ctan.

---

tabu probably needs an update to match the latest array, but you can force the use of the old array by using the new `[=...` optional argument to `\usepackage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}[=2016-10-06]
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=3pt


Result using tabu:

\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X[p]| X[m]| X[b]|}
    \hline
    \centering header p &
    \centering header m &   
    \centering header b \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column 
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabu}

\vspace*{1cm}

Result using tabular:

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|m{0.3\linewidth}|b{0.3\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    \centering header p &
    \centering header m &   
    \centering header b \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column 
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea what tabu should do to correct the problem, but the cause is that array now uses \vbox instead of \vcenter for the m-column and as tabu tests for `\currentgrouptype` it doesn't get 12 but 4 and so takes the wrong path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I didn't expect such a fast answer :). I found out that the problem persists if the \usepackage{siunitx} is loaded before. \usepackage{array}[=2016-10-06] should be loaded first to avoid any problems. Thank you!

Comment: @Micha I have mailed the tabu author pointing out this incompatibility, so hopefully he'll update to match the latest `array`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't hold your breath.