# Vertically aligning cells in tabu environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabu

I'm not sure if there's been a change to the `tabu` package, but in recompiling docs I've written before, vertical alignment of tabu cells no longer places content in the middle. For example,

```
\begin{tabu} to\textwidth {|X[c m]|X[m,c]|X[m,c]|}
    Hello & World & Long sentence that wraps around...
\end{tabu}
```

simply places all of the cell content at the very top. I've been able to hack around it by placing the cell content in a `varwidth` environment but it's incredibly taxing. I don't see any mention of a change to the package that would lead to this; have I always been doing this wrong?

Comment: Please edit your code so that we can compile your example - that's much more useful than just a fragment. Perhaps it is worth noting that the `tabu` package can't be recommended, since its author has promised backwards-incompatible changes at some point and meanwhile refuses to fix bugs. However, I would have expected the documentation to say so, so that's probably not the problem yet.

Comment: The version of `tabu` I have is from 2011: v. 2.8. So it hasn't changed in a while. Do you have the same?

Comment: Works for me. If anything, the first two cells seem to be lower - certainly not at the top of the cells.

Comment: @cfr, your version of `tabu` is the last one. but `array` is changed this year. since `tabu` is not maintained, it is not (and will not be) adopted to changes in `array`. a pity.

Comment: It seems to me that the same subject was discussed in the next post [tabu m-column vertical alignment not working after package updates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430973/154390)

Comment: @JLeonV. Thanks for passing this along! I've looked all over and couldn't find this. Great discussion on that post.

Comment: @Zarko This year must mean this month, as I'm pretty current - obviously not current enough. Well, we knew this would happen some time - we just assumed it would be when `tabu` was updated.